# Group data of linked document in aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We currently have the following code to group all documents from a collection by creation date:

```
this.aggregate( [
        { $match: { language: options.criteria.language, status: 1, type:{ $ne: "challenge" } }},
      { $group: {
          _id: {
              y: { '$year': '$created' },
              m: { '$month': '$created' },
              d: { '$dayOfMonth': '$created' },
              h: { '$hour': '$created' },
              min: { '$minute': '$created' },
              s: { '$second': '$created' }
          },
          count: { $sum : 1 }
        }},
        {$project: {
            date: "$_id", // so this is the shorter way
            count: 1,
            _id: 0
        }},
        { $sort: { "date": 1 } }

    ], function(err, result){

        if(err) {
          return callback(err);
        }


        callback(null, result);
    });
```

However, we now would like to group the results based on the start date instead of the creation date. The start date is not a field of the current collection, but it is a field of the `currentRevision` object, that is linked in this collection.

I tried this:

```
this.aggregate( [
        { $match: { language: options.criteria.language, status: 1, type:{ $ne: "challenge" } }},
      { $group: {
          _id: {
              y: { '$year': '$currentRevision.start_date' },
              m: { '$month': '$currentRevision.start_date' },
              d: { '$dayOfMonth': '$currentRevision.start_date' },
              h: { '$hour': '$currentRevision.start_date' },
              min: { '$minute': '$currentRevision.start_date' },
              s: { '$second': '$currentRevision.start_date' }
          },
          count: { $sum : 1 }
        }},
        {$project: {
            date: "$_id", // so this is the shorter way
            count: 1,
            _id: 0
        }},
        { $sort: { "date": 1 } }

    ], function(err, result){

        if(err) {
          return callback(err);
        }


        callback(null, result);
    });
```

but that just gives me an error: "failed to query db"

any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "linked document". Is the actual data in another collection referenced in your mongoose model? You cannot do that. MongoDB only operates on one collection at a time. Mongoose `.populate()` is not a join, but just the illusion of a join. All data needs to be in the same collection to aggregate it. Or you are doing processing in the client instead.

Comment: yes, it is indeed in another collection referenced. That's a pity, that it is not possible :(

Comment: It's actually a fundamental concept of using MongoDB. No joins. If you intend to use data as a query or collection point alongside other data then your design needs to put it in the same collection rather than reference it. You cannot just do all the same things you do with a relational database. The point is to design and store shema based on how you intend to use it, and not just what you are used to.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this with 2 queries perhaps?

Comment: No. You are still basically asking for a "join" as "startDate" is a property of documents in another collection. Your structure suggests this is `1:1` anyway, so having "linked" data serves no point. It's only a relational concept that has no place in MongoDB design that you are hanging on to. You might be referencing the same object in many places, so relational thinking says "use another table". But this is not how MongoDB works. Store the required data in your document, and hang the repetition. The gains likely outweigh the cost.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input :) will add it to the original schema then.

Comment: @BlakesSeven "linked" data can be used for audit trails if you treat the other collection as immutable. Think of it like a snapshot; every time you update a given document you save the entire updated (or prior) state in a separate collection. It can be much easier to manage than having an array of "to/from" on the document, as well as making aggregate/MR easier to manage.